# Заменить "копия" на "дубликат"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

Вопросы, являющиеся дубликатами, помечаются в заголовке общего потока вопросов как `[копия]`. При этом на странице самого вопроса в причинах используется слово "дубликат":

> отмечен как **дубликат** пользователями ...

> Данный вопрос был отмечен как **дубликат** уже существующего.

Более того, на Мете для обсуждения дубликатов как раз используется тег [дубликаты](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b) (хорошо бы убрать множественное число).

Предлагаю вместо `[копия]` писать всё же `[дубликат]`.

Comment: на Мете метку `дубликаты` оставить потому, что это тема про дубликаты а не про один дубликат.