# Нет перевода для “of” в тексте причины закрытия как «дубликат»

Tags: дефект, локализация, дубликаты

Текст причины закрытия как «дубликат» в [списке ревизий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/124185/revisions) содержит непереведенный предлог "of":

> [image: of]

Замутил баг на MSE: [Unable to translate “of” for duplicate notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303148/339911)

Comment: Тут недостаточно перевести только предлог. Нужна согласованная фраза.

Comment: @NickVolynkin если перевести как `вопроса` или `для` уже будет неплохо (закроет дыру в переводе). Но сделать нормальную фразу правильнее.

Comment: Необходимо помнить, что вопрос может быть закрыт несколькими участками! Единолично вопросы могут закрывать только модераторы и участники с золотом по метке.

Comment: Связанный вопрос [тут](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2178/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85).

Comment: А воз и ныне там.

Comment: @Suvitruf навоз там, а не воз :)

Comment: @alexolut воз с навозом.

Comment: @Suvitruf Покупатель, недовольный качеством навоза, не смог подобрать подходящего эпитета...

Answer (score 3):

В идеале хотелось бы поменять порядок частей составной строки:

> Вопрос закрыт как копия вопроса "Заголовок другого вопроса" участником Василий Пупкин.

Comment: Нет, там же список

Comment: Ну так местами поменять: "Вопрос закрыт участником/ами ... как копия следующего/их:"

Answer (score 0):

Можно действующее лицо сделать подлежащим. У глагола появится сдвоенное окончание, зато сама фраза станет прямее и короче:

> `Василий Пупкин` закрыл(а) этот вопрос как копию другого:
>   * `Заголовок другого вопроса`

UPD. Поскольку договорились копии называть [дубликатами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3723/):

> `Василий Пупкин` закрыл(а) этот вопрос как дубликат другого обсуждения:
>   * `Заголовок другого вопроса`
>   * `Заголовок ещё одного вопроса`

Comment: Кстати, я ведь не заметил, что там список. Вопросов-то может быть два.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Тоже не подумал об этом, но обрывать фразу на предлоге не хочется... И ещё договорились копии называть [дубликатами](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3723/).

Comment: @NickVolynkin дубликат сразу нескольких вопросов? А как же свойство транзитивности?

Comment: @GlebKemarsky кстати, хорошее замечание.